# maven plugin that download dependencies but failed to attach them to project compile scope in intellij (maven 3.9.0)

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3, maven-plugin, dependency-management, aether

We have a requirement to write a maven plugin that

1. downloads dependencies
2. add them to the **compile class-path** of **project**

download dependency logic is working as expected.

**But, when the project is opened in intellij,
downloaded library is not there in project compile classpath.**

---

**Attached a very simplified project on github to reproduce problem:-**

https://github.com/moglideveloper/download-dependencies-from-maven-plugin-example

Execute below commands to reproduce problem :-

```
git clone https://github.com/moglideveloper/download-dependencies-from-maven-plugin-example
cd download-dependencies-maven-plugin
mvn install

cd ../example-project
mvn clean compile
```

---

Below is the **DownloadDependencyMojo** configuration :-

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {

    Artifact aetherArtifact = new DefaultArtifact(groupId, artifactId, type, version);

    ArtifactRequest artifactRequest = new ArtifactRequest();
    artifactRequest.setArtifact(aetherArtifact);
    artifactRequest.setRepositories(remoteRepos);

    try {
        ArtifactResult aetherArtifactResult = repoSystem.resolveArtifact(repoSession, artifactRequest);
        Artifact resolvedAetherArtifact = aetherArtifactResult.getArtifact();

        getLog().info("Resolved aetherArtifact: " + resolvedAetherArtifact.getFile().getPath());

        project.addCompileSourceRoot(resolvedAetherArtifact.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
        org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact defaultArtifact = toMavenDefaultArtifact(resolvedAetherArtifact, "compile");
        project.addAttachedArtifact(defaultArtifact);

        Dependency compileScopeDependency = toDependency(resolvedAetherArtifact, "compile");
        project.getDependencies().add(compileScopeDependency);

        getLog().info("added to project: " + resolvedAetherArtifact.getFile().getPath());
    } catch (ArtifactResolutionException e) {
        throw new MojoExecutionException("failed to download dependencies", e);
    }
}
```

---

```
❯ mvn --version

Apache Maven 3.9.0 (9b58d2bad23a66be161c4664ef21ce219c2c8584)
Maven home: /Users/mogli/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current
Java version: 17.0.6, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /Users/mogli/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.6-tem
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.6.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: To be honest the two points you have mentioned are already done by Maven out of the box?? Furthermore the plugin you have mentioned mixes different things very very old version of the resolver, api etc. your mojo is not configured for dependency resolution etc... Apart from that all I don't not your intention for writing such a plugin or what kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: thanks @khmarbaise for your reply. our usecase : we have to fetch group id, artifact id, version from a rest api. they are hardcoded in this example for simplification.

Comment: Why fetching artifacts from REST API there exists a default which is called repository manager like (Nexus, Artifactory)... why something different? As I wrote.. I don't understand why you like to do such thing? Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: lot of our repositories are maven based, and sometimes their build starts failing in blackduck scan if the version is not correct  (https://www.synopsys.com/software-integrity/security-testing/software-composition-analysis.html). so correct versions we want to fetch using rest api.

Comment: attached github example is downloading dependency, but not getting added to compile scope when loaded in intellij. kindly suggest some references / or provide a pull request on my github example, it might be helpful for others as well, as there is not much simplified material on this on internet.